# OledbConnection Invalid Arguments

Tags: c#, data-driven-tests, data-driven

I try to read Excel file in Selenium Webdriver C# but got Invalid Arguments at **connection.Open()** . What am I wrong?

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;

namespace LeTuanAnh_Training.TestDataAccess
{
    class ExcelDataAccess
    {
        public static string TestDataFileConnection()
        {
            var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestDataSheetPath"];
            var con = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);
            return con;
        }

        public static UserData GetTestData(string keyName)
        {
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(TestDataFileConnection()))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var query = string.Format("select * from [Sheet1$] where key='{0}'", keyName);
                var value = connection.Query<UserData>(query).FirstOrDefault();
                connection.Close();
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings configSource="Configurations\Environment.config" />
</configuration>
```

Environment.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="TestDataSheetPath" value="TestDataAccess/Data.xlsx"/>
</appSettings>
```

[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TPoW.png)

Comment: can you please share with us the error ?

Comment: @mohammadmobasher I had add error picture, thanks

Comment: can you check value for "fileName" and tell me about the "con" variable?

Comment: another thing, why the editor keep challenge with  open and close database line code? 
is there any problem ?

Comment: @mohammadmobasher I just checked it and return null for fileName :( and the con variable is "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = ; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

Comment: so good luck, please fill the file name and test it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(TestDataFileConnection()))
```

The Using keyword open the connection and closes it when the using block ends. So you don't need the connection.Open() and the connection.Close().

Try to connect to your DB and double-check the DB connection data. Your question has nothing to do with Selenium...